# Maass forms associated with Ramanujan's mock theta functions

Tags: modular-forms, maass-forms, ramanujan

If you perform a fulltext search on the [L-functions and modular forms database](http://www.lmfdb.org/) for "Ramanujan", you get entries related to the $\tau$ function and the modular discriminant $\Delta$. If you want the list of mock theta functions which Ramanujan penned to Hardy in the last letter, those are [wikipedia: mock modular form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_modular_form) easy to find.

Is there a list of the Maass forms associated to Ramanujan's mock theta functions?

I want to try to render the nodal sets of those Maass forms in [kolam patterns](http://www.scipress.org/journals/forma/pdf/2201/22010031.pdf) for sentimental  reasons, more or less.